# Custom function to show subtitles in android VideoPlayer using textview by reading subtitle content from (.vtt) files when clicked on CC button

Tags: java, android, textview

If the subtitle file contains human errors and different data formats this function will be helpful i guess.

Call it in the CASE where rendering of the video starts

```
   case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START:
                try {
                    showAndLoadSubtitles();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Error", "ERROR!!!");
                }
```

This is the click function when tapped on CC image button

```
    private void newCCButtonClick() {
        if (ccEnabled) {
            ccEnabled = false;
            ib_new_cc.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_cc_button);
            tv_subtitle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            ccEnabled = true;
            ib_new_cc.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_cc_button_on);
            tv_subtitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

In the MediaController overriding methods adjust the visibility of CC button so that when the media controls disappears the cc button also gets hidden with them

```
        ctlr = new MediaController(VideoViewWithPlayList.this) {
            @Override
            public void show() {
                showSubtitleViews();
                repositionSubtitle(true);
                super.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void hide() {
                ib_new_cc.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                repositionSubtitle(false);
                super.hide();
            }
        };


    private void showSubtitleViews() {
        if (srtOfflineFilePathName != null) {
            if (srtOfflineFilePathName.contains(subTitleType_VTT) ||
                    srtOfflineFilePathName.contains(subTitleType_VTTCap)) {

                File file = new File(srtOfflineFilePathName);
                if (file.length() > 0) {
                    ib_new_cc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else ib_new_cc.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if (ccEnabled) {
                    tv_subtitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ib_new_cc.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_cc_button_on);
                } else {
                    tv_subtitle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    ib_new_cc.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_cc_button);
                }
            } else {
                ib_new_cc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tv_subtitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the main function `showAndLoadSubtitles` where subtitle data is being handled and inflated into a textview by using a timer

```
    private void showAndLoadSubtitles() {
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }

        /*New methods for customSubtitle using textView*/
        if (srtOfflineFilePathName != null) {
            if (srtOfflineFilePathName.contains(subTitleType_VTT) ||
                    srtOfflineFilePathName.contains(subTitleType_VTTCap)) {

                try {
                    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(srtOfflineFilePathName);
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

                    String line;
                    boolean startReading = false; // Flag to indicate whether to start reading lines
                    StringBuilder subtitleContent = new StringBuilder();

                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        // Reached the timestamp, start reading lines
                        if (line.startsWith("00:00")) startReading = true;

                        // Process the line as needed
                        if (startReading) subtitleContent.append(line).append("\n");
                    }

                    bufferedReader.close();

                    if (subtitleContent.length() > 0) {

                        List<NewSubtitleModel> newSubtitleModelList = new ArrayList<>();
                        String[] subtitles = subtitleContent.toString().split("\n\n");

                        for (String subtitle : subtitles) {
                            // Split the subtitle into timestamp and text
                            String[] lines = subtitle.split("\n");

                            // The remaining lines are the subtitle text
                            StringBuilder subtitleText = new StringBuilder();
                            for (int i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
                                subtitleText.append(lines[i]).append("\n");
                            }

                            long startTime = 0L;
                            long endTime = 0L;
                            String subTitleData = "";
                            String[] timestamps;

                            /*Since there are unwanted data coming in the timestamp
                            line trimming off and taking only the timestamp
                            value by using substring*/
                            String properTimeStampData = "";

                            /*Splitting timestamps to start and end time*/
                            if (lines[0] != null && !lines[0].equals("")) {

                                if (!lines[0].trim().contains(":")) {
                                    /*Subtitle with serial number format condition*/
                                    properTimeStampData = lines[1].substring(0, 29);
                                    timestamps = properTimeStampData.split("-->");
                                    subTitleData = lines[2].trim();
                                } else {
                                    properTimeStampData = lines[0].substring(0, 29);
                                    timestamps = properTimeStampData.split("-->");
                                    subTitleData = subtitleText.toString().trim();
                                }

                                startTime = parseTimestamp(timestamps[0].trim());
                                endTime = parseTimestamp(timestamps[1].trim());

                            } else {
                                /*Taking timestamp and subtitle content for the first item*/
                                if (lines[1] != null && !lines[1].equals("")) {
                                    String[] linesData = subtitleText.toString().split("\n");

                                    properTimeStampData = linesData[0].substring(0, 29);
                                    String[] newTimeStamps = properTimeStampData.split("-->");

                                    startTime = parseTimestamp(newTimeStamps[0].trim());
                                    endTime = parseTimestamp(newTimeStamps[1].trim());
                                    subTitleData = linesData[1].trim();
                                }
                            }

                            /*Subtitles are saved into this modelList*/
                            NewSubtitleModel newSubtitleModel = new NewSubtitleModel
                                    (startTime, endTime, subTitleData);
                            newSubtitleModelList.add(newSubtitleModel);

                        }

                        // Start a timer to update the subtitles
                        timer = new Timer();
                        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    int currentPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
                                    // Find the subtitle corresponding to the current position
                                    String subtitle = findSubtitleForPosition(newSubtitleModelList, currentPosition);

                                    // Set the subtitle text on the TextView
                                    runOnUiThread(() -> {
                                        if (subtitle != null) {
                                            tv_subtitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(subtitle));
                                            tv_subtitle.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#42000000"));
                                        } else {
                                            tv_subtitle.setText("");
                                            tv_subtitle.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FFFFFF"));
                                        }

                                    });
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }, 0, 100); // Update every 100 milliseconds
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private long parseTimestamp(String timestamp) {
        if (timestamp != null && !timestamp.equals("")) {
            String[] timeComponents = timestamp.split(":");
            int hours = Integer.parseInt(timeComponents[0]);
            int minutes = Integer.parseInt(timeComponents[1]);
            float seconds = Float.parseFloat(timeComponents[2].replace(",", "."));
            long totalMilliseconds = (long) (hours * 3600 * 1000 + minutes * 60 * 1000 + seconds * 1000);
            return totalMilliseconds;
        } else return 0L;
    }

    private String findSubtitleForPosition(List<NewSubtitleModel> newSubtitleModelList, int currentPosition) {
        for (NewSubtitleModel newSubtitleModel : newSubtitleModelList) {
            if (currentPosition >= newSubtitleModel.getStartTime() &&
                    currentPosition <= newSubtitleModel.getEndTime()) {
                return newSubtitleModel.getSubtitleText();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I tried manually cutting down the string content inside the VTT file and result is working fine